# batch increment variable string

Tags: batch-file

I need your help please. I have a problem with concatenate.

```
SET /A "index=1"

for /f "skip=%index%" %%G IN (anoiarseeds.txt)   DO if not defined var%index% set "var%index%=%%G"
```

This code is working but the problem in the next step how can I echo the value of `var%index%` ?

`%var%%index%` doesn't work.

`!%var%%index%%!` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

You essentially have two options.

The first one requires the use of delayed variable expansion.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SET /A "index=1"
for /f "skip=%index%" %%G IN (anoiarseeds.txt) DO if not defined var%index% set "var%index%=%%G"
echo !var%index%!
```

The second option is getting two phases of expansion using the `CALL` command.

```
@echo off
SET /A "index=1"
for /f "skip=%index%" %%G IN (anoiarseeds.txt) DO if not defined var%index% set "var%index%=%%G"
call echo %%var%index%%%
```

Comment: Didn't know about the second option with a `call`, thanks. There is one caveat with it though: try changing the name of the loop variable from `%%G` to `%%v` and see what happens. I guess it was not supposed to be used like this, the parser fails if the first letter of the variable to be expanded is the same as the loop variable.